# SQL: How to bring back records when a value in a specific column has changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following example table below:

```
DateAndTime         MainsGasMeter   Product_Order_MSB   Product_Order_LSB
  21/02/2017 03:53  53338200            7556                   4331
  21/02/2017 03:52  53338200            7556                   4331
  21/02/2017 03:51  53338200            7556                   4331
  21/02/2017 03:50  53338200            7556                   4331
  21/02/2017 03:49  53338100            7556                   4324
  21/02/2017 03:48  53338100            7556                   4324
  21/02/2017 03:47  53338100            7556                   4324
  21/02/2017 03:46  53338000            7556                   4324
  21/02/2017 03:45  53338000            7556                   4324
  21/02/2017 03:44  53338000            7556                   4324
  21/02/2017 03:43  53338000            7556                   4324
  21/02/2017 03:42  53337900            7556                   4324
  21/02/2017 03:41  53337900            7556                   4324
  21/02/2017 03:40  53337900            7556                   4324
  21/02/2017 03:39  53337900            7556                   4323
  21/02/2017 03:38  53337900            7556                   4323
  21/02/2017 03:37  53337900            7556                   4323
  21/02/2017 03:36  53337800            7556                   4323
  21/02/2017 03:35  53337800            7556                   4323
  21/02/2017 03:34  53337800            7556                   4323
```

Can I write an SQL query in which it only brings back the line of data when `Product_Order_LSB` changes?

The code should bring back this result:

```
DateAndTime         MainsGasMeter   Product_Order_MSB   Product_Order_LSB
21/02/2017 03:50    53338200            7556                    4331
21/02/2017 03:40    53337900            7556                    4324
```

The source of the data is `FurnaceHist.dbo.Furnace_db Furnace_db`.

I am new to SQL so any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql Server? What version?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: does your table have a primary key, and if so what type is it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming version is 2012 or higher, you can use the `LAG` function to get the previous value, and do something like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DateAndTime, 
           MainsGasMeter, 
           Product_Order_MSB, 
           Product_Order_LSB,
           LAG(Product_Order_LSB) 
               OVER(PARTITION BY MainsGasMeter ORDER BY DateAndTime) prevValue
      FROM TableName
 )

 SELECT  DateAndTime, 
         MainsGasMeter, 
         Product_Order_MSB, 
         Product_Order_LSB
 FROM CTE
 WHERE PrevValue IS NULL
 OR Product_Order_LSB <> PrevValue
```

For older versions, you can use a sub query instead of `LAG`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DateAndTime, 
           MainsGasMeter, 
           Product_Order_MSB, 
           Product_Order_LSB,
           ( 
                SELECT TOP 1 Product_Order_LSB
                FROM TableName tSub
                WHERE tSub.MainsGasMeter = tMain.MainsGasMeter 
                AND tSub.DateAndTime < tMain.DateAndTime
                ORDER BY DateAndTime DESC
           ) prevValue
       FROM TableName tMain
 )

 SELECT  DateAndTime, 
         MainsGasMeter, 
         Product_Order_MSB, 
         Product_Order_LSB
 FROM CTE
 WHERE PrevValue IS NULL
 OR Product_Order_LSB <> PrevValue
```

Comment: Hi again,

We have the older version.
The query works but its bringing back the lines of data when the 'MainsGasMeter' changes not the 'Product _Order_LSB'. 

Thank you,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

This query may be useful to you. Assuming you have version lower than 2012.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY  ProductOrderLSB ORDER BY ProductOrderLSB) AS RN
    FROM tblTempTableDates)

SELECT  C1.Dates, 
    C1.MainGasMeter, 
    C1.ProductOrderMSB, 
    C1.ProductOrderLSB FROM CTE C1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ProductOrderLSB, 
        MAX(RN) AS RowNumber2 
        FROM CTE 
        GROUP BY ProductOrderLSB
        ) C2
ON C1.RN =  C2.RowNumber2 AND C1.ProductOrderLSB = C2.ProductOrderLSB
```